# Setting python path for sublimerepl from sublime text?

Tags: python, sublimetext, pythonpath, sublimerepl

I use python portable along with sublime portable of a memory stick and decided to install sublime REPL however when trying to use python portable as the build path for sublimerepl it does not specify it.

To put it simply I can't specify the sublimerepl python path like I can with straight sublime text!

I have tried adding the following into SublimeREPL.sublime-settings

`"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:C:\\Users\\Andy\\Documents\\_Main\\M-Stick                               Backups\\08.07.13\\Computing\\Python Portable\\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\\App\\python.exe"},`

I have also tried changing:

`"cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"],`

to

`"cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Andy\\Documents\\_Main\\M-Stick Backups\\08.07.13\\Computing\\Python Portable\\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\\App\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],`

within Python/Main.sublime-menu

Note in normal sublime I add the following to Python.sublime-build:

`{"cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Andy\\Documents\\_Main\\M-Stick Backups\\08.07.13\\Computing\\Python Portable\\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\\App\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],"file_regex": "^[ ]*Iile \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)","selector": "source.python"}`

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're changing the wrong line of code in `/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`? If you wish to run REPL on the current file,

```
{"command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
 "mnemonic": "d",
 "args": {
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Andy\\Documents\\_Main\\M-Stick Backups\\08.07.13\\Computing\\Python Portable\\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\\App\\python.exe", "-u", "$file_basename"],
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
    }
```

is what the modified section should look like. (It appears you might be modifying the command which opens the interpreter in interactive mode as opposed to running the current file).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm using the Eval in repl >> block command, do you know where I can edit that command?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hower... I installed the package control, then the sublimePREPL package and, then in the keybinding (under preferences) I wrote this int the user file:

[

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
 "mnemonic": "d",
 "args": {
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\giova\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe", "-u", "$file_basename"],
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
        }}
]
```