# Change Python version for evaluating file with SublimREPL plugin

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3, osx-elcapitan, sublimerepl

I am using Sublim Text 3 on Mac OS X El Capitan. What I need to do is to evaluate a Python file within Sublime Text 3.

I have installed `Package Control` and then `SublimREPL` plugins.

I have set up a 2 rows layout (`View > Layout > Rows: 2`) in order to display a Python interpreter in the second part of the screen.

I then launch the Python interpreter with `Tools > Command Palette... > SublimeREPL: Python`.

[image]

The interpreter starts correctly and I get this:

[image]

I can't find how to start with Python 3.5 that I have downloaded manually (thus installed in `/usr/local/bin/`). I have tried to modify this file: `/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/Config/Python/Main.sublime-menu` following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575258/2508539) instructions, but this did not change anything (Python 2.7.10 still launched).

Here is the content of my `Main.sublime-menu`:

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "R",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python",
                     "id": "repl_python",
                     "mnemonic": "P",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    },
                    {"command": "python_virtualenv_repl",
                     "id": "python_virtualenv_repl",
                     "caption": "Python - virtualenv"},
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - PDB current file",
                     "id": "repl_python_pdb",
                     "mnemonic": "D",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    },
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
                     "id": "repl_python_run",
                     "mnemonic": "R",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file_basename"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    },
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - IPython",
                     "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                     "mnemonic": "I",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "autocomplete_server": true,
                        "cmd": {
                            "osx": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                            "linux": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                            "windows": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"]
                        },
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {
                            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                            "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                ]}
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Still following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575258/2508539) advices, I modified the part of code below, but I can't find any exe file in folder `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
{"command": "repl_open",
"caption": "Python - PDB current file",
"id": "repl_python_pdb",
"mnemonic": "D",
"args": {
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-i", "-u", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
    }
}
```

When I press `Ctrl` + `,` + `f` (according to the [doc](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/README.md)), the interpreter still starts with Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Not intimately familiar with OSX but with linux the Python3.x installation will have the executable named to something like `python3` or `python35`.  If `/usr/local/bin/` is empty like you mentioned then any chance it was installed into `/usr/bin` and if not what about `/Library/Frameworks/` or even just in Applications?

Comment: Another thing to try, on the command line if you can get python3 to run, `whereis python` or `which python` would tell you where it is located.   Similarly, inside the Python 3 interpreter `import site; print(site.USER_SITE)` "should" print out the location of python3's site-packages directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are modifying the incorrect configuration files and perhaps a few things are causing issues.

> I then launch the Python interpreter with `Tools > Command Palette... > SublimeREPL: Python`

There is no command palette item "SublimeREPL: Python", so I'm assuming you mean `Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python`. That opens in a tab something like the following:

```
# *REPL* [python]
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

In fact `Tools > SublimeREPL > Python` displays a menu something like the following:

```
Python - execnet
Python
Python - virtualen
Python - PDB current file
Python - RUN current file
Python - IPython
```

So far so good. But how to change the Python version?

Ideally we could either configure the global python to use (that doesn't seem possible) or add a version variant to the menus desccribed above (that doesn't seem possible either).

The most straight forward workaround is adding a custom version variant.

Create a file named `Packages/User/Main.sublime-menu` (if it doesn't already exist). Find the User packages  directory via `Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...`). And create your menu in that file. This menu will be **added** to the existing menus.

For example:

`Packages/User/Main.sublime-menu`

```
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL Variants",
            "id": "SublimeREPLVariants",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "command": "repl_open",
                    "caption": "Python - PDB current file",
                    "id": "repl_python_pdb",
                    "mnemonic": "D",
                    "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-i", "-u", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

It is important that:

1. The caption and id are not the same as any other menu otherwise it will replace the other menu, hence I've named the one above "SublimeREPL Variants".
2. The "cmd" uses an absolute path to a valid binary. You can check you are using the correct path with a commands like `which`:

Find the location of Python via which:

```
    $ which python
    /usr/bin/python

    $ which python3
    /usr/bin/python3

    $ which python2
    /usr/bin/python2
```

See also [Possible to switch between python 2 and 3 in Sublime Text 3 build systems? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024713/possible-to-switch-between-python-2-and-3-in-sublime-text-3-build-systems-wind/40031389#40031389) for additional details.

Comment: There is indeed a `Tools > Command Palette... > SublimeREPL: Python` menu: see my post I've edited and added a screenshot.

Comment: I tried your solution and it did the job perfectly anyway. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On my system (windows) the file needs to be named Main.sublime-menu instead of Menu.sublime-menu. Other than that, this was exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks for that.